# Mathematical models of oscillatory chemical reactions

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, theoretical-chemistry

I am a mathematician working on real-life models in ordinary differential equations. I want to know if there are any models of oscillatory chemical reactions that consist of three ordinary differential equations where one variable is much slower than the other two. In particular I am interested in bursting behavior, which consists of alternating trains of fast oscillations with periods of rest.

I have been searching and I couldn't find what I am looking for. I found about the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction, but in this case we have one fast variable and two slow variables, while I'm looking for two fast variables and one slow variable.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/267/30836)

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8812/5

Comment: related? https://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/60495/1/WRAP_computation-02-00047.pdf